# Golang Split String with Regexp

Tags: regex, go

I have a string and I split the string with regexp package. However I could not create a regexp I need.

The regexp code lines:

```
v = "@636e0e0eac0bd25cd5df92a3$636e0e49ac0bd25cd5df92a5.result.result[0].code.xTrim()"
r, _ := regexp.Compile(`(@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.*)`)
variableParts := r.FindStringSubmatch(v)
```

VariablesParts array:

0: "@636e0e0eac0bd25cd5df92a3$636e0e49ac0bd25cd5df92a5.result.result[0].code.xTrim()"

1: "@636e0e0eac0bd25cd5df92a3$636e0e49ac0bd25cd5df92a5"

2: ".result.result[0].code.xTrim()"

This is my desired result:

Array length can change but array should include this 4 strings.

0: "@636e0e0eac0bd25cd5df92a3$636e0e49ac0bd25cd5df92a5.result.result[0].code.xTrim()"

1: "@636e0e0eac0bd25cd5df92a3$636e0e49ac0bd25cd5df92a5"

2: ".result.result[0].code.xTrim()"

3: ".xTrim()"

How Can I get this result. Which regexp string I need?

---

UPDATE for new desired result:

1: "@636e0e0eac0bd25cd5df92a3$636e0e49ac0bd25cd5df92a5"

2: ".result.result[0].code.xTrim()"

3: ".result"

4: ".result[0]"

5: ".code"

6: ".xTrim()"

Comment: Why are you using regex?  `strings.Split` would be a lot simpler (and faster)

Comment: As for the problem with your regex:  You probably mean `\.(.*)` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the last `(.*)` part with `(.*(\.[^.]*))$` and use

```
(@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.*(\.[^.]*))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q3svdX/1). *Details*:

- `(@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+)` - Group 1: a `@` char, then one or more alphanumeric chars, then a `#` char and then again one or more alphanumeric chars
- `(.*(\.[^.]*))` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then Group 3: a `.`, zero or more chars other than a `.` char
- `$` - at the end of string. Remove if there can be more text on the right.

Comment: It worked, also I edited question for new desired result. How should I change regexp string to get the new result?

Comment: @oakkose Split with `.`, e.g. ``strings.Split(text,`.`)``. Or match with `[^.]+` regex, e.g. [here](https://regex101.com/r/q3svdX/2)

Comment: I updated desired result again. With strings.Split I can not get the result.  How should regex string be?

Comment: @oakkose You can only use regex for this if you know the maximum number of substrings you want to capture. Then just add the optional groups, see https://regex101.com/r/q3svdX/3